# Arraylist on FORM 2 put into an Listbox Form3

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

I have got some code that gathers all textboxs and stores them as an arraylist, then all combo boxs stores as a second list, this is "working" however it seems to be putting box's 2-10 from top to bottom, them the first box on the bottom, and it say box 1,2,3,4,5 were populated 6-10 not, you will get 2,3,4,5, then 5 blank lines, then box 1 at the bottom.
I am wondering how i can stop this? i.e make it ignore empty boxs. once i get to 15 rep i will post some pictures of this project and ask for alot of help in various fields i am struggling. the code in use is as follows
FORM 2 - the collection

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim f As New Form3()
    Dim allValues As New List(Of String)()
    For Each xTextBoxes As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        f.i.AddRange(xTextBoxes.Text.Split(","))
    Next
    Dim allValues2 As New List(Of String)()
    For Each xComboBoxes As ComboBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
        f.l.AddRange(xComboBoxes.Text.Split(","))
    Next
    f.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

The the print out in Form 3

```
Public i As New List(Of String)()
Public l As New List(Of String)()

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(i.ToArray())
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(l.ToArray())
End Sub
```

if i has textbox 1,2,3,4 populated with 111,111,111 then 222,222,222 then 33,33 and 44,44
This is how it would display in the Listbox

222
222
222
33
33
44
44
(blank Line)
(blank Line)
(blank Line)
(blank Line)
(blank Line)
(blank Line)
111
111
111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option when calling the `Split` method, like this:

```
f.i.AddRange(xTextBoxes.Text.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

If, for some reason, that doesn't work, I'd just check if the value was empty before using it:

```
If xTextBoxes.Text <> String.Empty Then
    f.i.AddRange(xTextBoxes.Text.Split(","))
End If
```

By the way, you aren't actually using `allValues` or `allValues2` anywhere...

Comment: You are fastly becoming my hero!
Dunno if i am annoying you yet. but it might help reduce how much i pester if you knew a good place to read up on all this sort of stuff?
I have one more question regarding this section of my program... for now!
Oh FYI, the first suggestions did not like the ","c section, would not build the program, then threw a fit if i removed the c too :) The second section has fixed all the problems i was getting

Comment: Oops.  Sorry about that.  I fixed the first example.  The `c` after a single character string (e.g. `","c`) indicates that it is a character rather than a string.  In other C-ish languages, such as C#, you use single quotes for characters and double quotes for strings (e.g. `"example string"` for a string and `'a'` for a character), but in VB.NET, it's a bit more confusing because it uses double quotes for both, but uses the `c` suffix to denote characters (e.g. `"example string"` for a string and `"a"c` for a character).

Comment: The `c` suffix for characters is, at least, consistent with the way suffixes are used for other types of literals, such as `D` for `Decimal` literals (e.g. `1.3D`) and `F` for `Single` literals (e.g. `1.3F`).

Comment: No, you're not annoying me yet :)  I don't have any great learning material suggestions.  The help system in visual studio, which is essentially just a wrapper around the online MSDN documentation is the best place to go for reference material.  But as far as tutorials and things like that, I don't have any idea.  I've always been one to get more out of reading specifications than from following examples.  I've always liked O'Reilly safari books the best, and I know that they have various "cookbooks" which are more geared around practical tutorials, but I've never read one...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a for-loop or for-each instead of addrange and only transfer nonempty items, or iterate through the list and remove the empty ones.

Also you may like to change the form creation to singleton, so make sure the data that you try to access from form3 is the same that is also the running one.

Is it wrong coding or do you need Lists of arrays? maybe you can explain that? (this is not direct solution, but may also help you to improve your coding a bit)